# Iterating over a string and giving the number of characters using if in the form of a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm watching a video on dictionaries in Python, and I've come across the following code:

```
logs = 'rwgojnerjblebwegijerjgnoeabgjnawprijgeqwpowepfiwejgpnegparsgb'
logs_count = {}
for char in logs:
    if char == 'j':
        if char in logs_count:
            logs_count[char] += 1
        else:
            logs_count[char] = 1

print(logs_count)
```

How can `if char in logs_count` evaluate to `True` if `logs_count` is empty?

And for `logs_count[char] += 1`, how can we add 1 if we haven't assigned any value to the `char` key?

Comment: `if char in logs_count` won't evaluate to True if the dict is empty. In that case, the `else` clause runs, which assigns the value to dict,  after which the dict is no longer empty.

Comment: And, as a semirelated side note, you can replace that whole thing with two lines by doing `from collections import Counter` / `logs_count = Counter(logs)`.